# Hibernate QueryImpl.list optimization

Tags: mysql, hibernate, query-optimization, hql

I have a Task table containing 144 records(rows). I am fetching all the records using a normal select query but time taken by the method as reported by JProfiler is too much for this little amount of data.

[Here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ImngNxeKFL4/UWZQj3WQvwI/AAAAAAAAAnw/lXXlOjr8aK8/w1499-h428-p-o/jprofiler.png) is the snapshot of JProfiler.

My concern is the time taken by **org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list** . When i run normal sql query in a database tool, it takes 0.016 seconds to fetch all the records, but here it is taking much more time.

How can i reduce this time and upto what extent? Could this really be reduced ? or about 3 seconds is ok ?

Database used is MySql.

Below is the method which fetches the date

```
public List<Backlog> findBacklogList() {
    Query query = (Query) getSession().createQuery("from Backlog");
    List<Backlog> backlogList = (List<Backlog>) query.list();
    return backlogList;
}
```

Below is the Backlog Pojo

```
public class Backlog implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long taskId;
private String taskName;
private TaskType taskType;
private Member createdBy; // String
private Date createdDate;
private Member updatedBy; // String
private Date updatedOn;
private Status status;
private Priority priority;
private String approved;
private Member completedBy;
private Member ownedBy;
private BacklogGroup group;
private Set<OtherPeople> otherPeople;
private String activeStatus;
private String statusChanged;
private String description;
private Date expectedEndDate;

/**
 * @return the taskId
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "taskid", nullable = false, unique = true, insertable = false)
public Long getTaskId() {
    return taskId;
}

/**
 * @param taskId
 *            the taskId to set
 */
public void setTaskId(Long taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
}

/**
 * @return the taskName
 */
@Column(name = "taskname", nullable = false, unique = true)
public String getTaskName() {
    return taskName;
}

/**
 * @param taskName
 *            the taskName to set
 */
public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}

/**
 * @return the taskType
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "tasktype", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
public TaskType getTaskType() {
    return taskType;
}

/**
 * @param taskType
 *            the taskType to set
 */
public void setTaskType(TaskType taskType) {
    this.taskType = taskType;
}

/**
 * @return the createdDate
 */
@Column(name = "createdDate", nullable = false)
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

/**
 * @param createdDate
 *            the createdDate to set
 */
public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

/**
 * @return the updatedBy
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "updatedBy")
public Member getUpdatedBy() {
    return updatedBy;
}

/**
 * @param updatedBy
 *            the updatedBy to set
 */
public void setUpdatedBy(Member updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}

/**
 * @return the updatedOn
 */
@Column(name = "updatedOn")
public Date getUpdatedOn() {
    return updatedOn;
}

/**
 * @param updatedOn
 *            the updatedOn to set
 */
public void setUpdatedOn(Date updatedOn) {
    this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
}

/**
 * @return the status
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "status", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

/**
 * @param status
 *            the status to set
 */
public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

/**
 * @return the priority
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "priority", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
public Priority getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

/**
 * @param priority
 *            the priority to set
 */
public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

/**
 * @return the approved
 */
@Column(name = "approved")
public String getApproved() {
    return approved;
}

/**
 * @param approved
 *            the approved to set
 */
public void setApproved(String approved) {
    this.approved = approved;
}

/**
 * @return the completedBy
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "completedBy")
public Member getCompletedBy() {
    return completedBy;
}

/**
 * @param completedBy
 *            the completedBy to set
 */
public void setCompletedBy(Member completedBy) {
    this.completedBy = completedBy;
}

/**
 * @return the otherPeople
 */
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<OtherPeople> getOtherPeople() {
    return otherPeople;
}

/**
 * @param otherPeople
 *            the otherPeople to set
 */
public void setOtherPeople(Set<OtherPeople> otherPeople) {
    this.otherPeople = otherPeople;
}

/**
 * @return the group
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "groupid", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
public BacklogGroup getGroup() {
    return group;
}

/**
 * @param group
 *            the group to set
 */
public void setGroup(BacklogGroup group) {
    this.group = group;
}

/**
 * @return the createdBy
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "createdBy", nullable = false)
public Member getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

/**
 * @param createdBy
 *            the createdBy to set
 */
public void setCreatedBy(Member createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

/**
 * @return the activeStatus
 */
@Column(name = "activeStatus")
public String getActiveStatus() {
    return activeStatus;
}

/**
 * @param activeStatus
 *            the activeStatus to set
 */
public void setActiveStatus(String activeStatus) {
    this.activeStatus = activeStatus;
}

/**
 * @return the statusChanged
 */
@Column(name = "statusChanged")
public String getStatusChanged() {
    return statusChanged;
}

@Column(name = "expectedEndDate")
public Date getExpectedEndDate() {
    return expectedEndDate;
}

public void setExpectedEndDate(Date expectedEndDate) {
    this.expectedEndDate = expectedEndDate;
}

/**
 * @param statusChanged
 *            the statusChanged to set
 */
public void setStatusChanged(String statusChanged) {
    this.statusChanged = statusChanged;
}

/**
 * @return the description
 */
@Column(name = "description", length = 5000)
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

/**
 * @param description
 *            the description to set
 */
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

/**
 * @return the ownedBy
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ownedBy", nullable = false)
public Member getOwnedBy() {
    return ownedBy;
}

/**
 * @param ownedBy the ownedBy to set
 */
public void setOwnedBy(Member ownedBy) {
    this.ownedBy = ownedBy;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((taskId == null) ? 0 : taskId.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Backlog)) {
        return false;
    }
    Backlog other = (Backlog) obj;
    if (taskId == null) {
        if (other.taskId != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!taskId.equals(other.taskId)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Post the normal query which takes 0.016 seconds to fetch all data.

Comment: select * from backlog

Comment: as koljaTM said, your Backlog class has various associated pojos which are set to fetch eagerly. So when you fetch this queries to fetch this associated data are also executed. Its good practice to make the associated properties to loaded lazily, it will reduce the amount of time required to fetch Backlog data.

Comment: Thanks code13, that lazy fetching did the trick and reduced the time to 1205ms, but again with this, **org.hibernate.PersistentSet.isEmpty** is being invoked which additionally taking 1705ms adding the total time for the method to come out to be 3 sec. What more could be done in this case?
[jprofile snapshot](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-E0KW_zFELGo/UWZW7yH2edI/AAAAAAAAAoE/5UW83-unOS4/s555/jprofiler2.png)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the query is getting all associated data as well, e.g. the otherPeople Set, which might be large. Try to activate hibernate sql logging to see which statements are actually executed. If you are getting a a separate subquery for each result row (or even multiple), you might have a problem. Consider not fetching eagerly or setting some relations to FetchJoin, so that the data is joined immediately, if you know you are going to need it.
If you don't need the data, don't select it. Sometimes it can also be a good idea to build an extra object just for querying, if you are interested in a large number of results but only a smaller subset of the data in it (e.g. for an overview list).

Comment: Thanks koljaTM, that lazy fetching did the trick and reduced the time to 1205ms, but again with this, **org.hibernate.PersistentSet.isEmpty** is being invoked which additionally taking 1705ms adding the total time for the method to come out to be 3 sec. What more could be done in this case?

Comment: [jprofiler snapshot](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-E0KW_zFELGo/UWZW7yH2edI/AAAAAAAAAoE/5UW83-unOS4/s555/jprofiler2.png)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to reduce the time required for fetch data while using Hibernate is to use Lazy loading where ever possible.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)// This will take more time
```

In your pojo change EAGER loading to LAZY if possible.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Other thing is to enable printing the queries executed by Hibernate, there you can see how many actual queries are getting executed to fetch single object.

You can do this by setting hibernate.show_sql property to true in your hibernate configuration.

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

You can read more about hibernate optimization at [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html).

Comment: Hi code13, I already did that and reduced the time, but as u can see on comments above, there is a new problem for time with PersistentSet class. Please refer the [snapshot](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-E0KW_zFELGo/UWZW7yH2edI/AAAAAAAAAoE/5UW83-unOS4/s555/jprofiler2.png)